# How to get array length instead of full array in find()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongodb (using mongoose) collection ("items") which includes an array ("images") among its properties.  Some example documents:

```
[
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("543fa67e9672ec37ebe3d026"),
    "name" : "Alice",
    "images" : [
      { url: "http://images.com/1.jpg" },
      { url: "http://images.com/2.jpg" },
      { url: "http://images.com/3.jpg" },
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("543fa67e9672ec37ebe3d027"),
    "name" : "Bob",
    "images" : [
      { url: "http://images.com/4.jpg" },
      { url: "http://images.com/5.jpg" },
    ]
  },
]
```

I want to implement a query which returns - along with other document properties - the array length (and not the array contents). I know I can get the array length with

```
db.items.aggregate([
  { "$project" : { "_id" : 0, "imagesLength" : { "$size" : "$images" } } }
])
```

But I need the `imagesLength` values along with the documents returned with a find:

```
db.items.findMany(
  { ...filter },
  { name: 1, imagesCount: 1 }
);
```

**The question is:** how can I get the array length along with the `find` results ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do same as aggregation projection in find's second argument,
[Starting in MongoDB 4.4](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#find-projection), as part of making find projection consistent with aggregation’s `$project` stage,

```
db.items.find(
{ ...filter },
{
  _id: 0,
  name: 1,
  images: { $size: "$images" }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fg_L20tctrI)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a match stage at first in your aggregation to filter the results. Then you can project all fields needed and generate the new ones.

```
db.items.aggregate([
  { "$match" : { ...filter },
  { "$project" : { "imagesLength" : { "$size" : "$images" }, "name": 1 } }
])
```